# Hooks in setuptools/distutils for post-install verification

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

I have a package that uses `swig` to generate some C++ interfaces to an external library, specifically `udunits-2`. On some systems, namely CentOS, the package will install successfully but when python tries to load the library an import error is raised.

`ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libudunits2.so.0: undefined symbol:`

I solved the issue on the systems by reinstalling `udunits-2` but it is really tedious to find out that the library failed after deployment to the systems.

Is there a convention or mechanism to try to simply test the import resolution after `setup` is done installing the package?  Ultimately, all I need is to try to import the module to see if the import succeeds but what would be really nice is to run a quick test that ensures the classes can all be instantiated.

Any documentation or leads would be awesome!

Comment: I think there is/was a practice to run package tests after package install to know if it works properly on the system. However, not sure if people actually do this.

Comment: Apparently there is a test feature in setup but it doesn't do or test what I was hoping, the best I can hope for is that the users that install the package actually run a test-suite.